# how to remove gap between the app and gesture navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

There is a gap between the bottom of my app and the android 10's navigation bar.

This is how my app looks
[image: My app]

I want that to look like the one below. i want the black portion of the app to integrate with my app's white while the bar could be set to the colour grey.

[image: Desired Effect]

I'm on the latest android studio and my api level is at  android 8 and above.

Comment: You're question seems to be about how to change the color of the navigation bar, not how to get rid of a gap (there isn't a gap?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should modify your theme of the activity and put the navigation bar transparent

Comment: where can i do that ?

Comment: in ressource file  <style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>replace parent by Theme.AppCompat